PHP Date Format Issue on blank date fields
strtotime return wrong value upon blank field - form submission
Date selection is working fine but empty field giving 01-01-1970
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="DOB"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="BtnSubmit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["BtnSubmit"]))
{$F_DOB = $_POST["DOB"];
$F_DOBNew = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($F_DOB));
echo $F_DOBNew;}
?>

Above is the code what I am doing and working fine upon clicking the button. Few date fields are not required so when a user click on the button and left the date fields empty, the empty date fields shows 01-01-1970 upon submission.

Why base the code on whether or not the button value is present in the POST array rather than the value of DOB?

Can you help to resolve this please? What is the solution?

It's not quite clear what value you want instead of 01-01-1970. You could do: strtotime(empty($F_DOB) ? "now" : $F_DOB) if you want the current data. See: https://3v4l.org/oZ7cI

...Few date fields are not required... - the above shows a single date field - are there others in the form? What are you doing with the form content - adding to db?

KIKO Software: Should be empty if the user is not selecting the date from the input date field.

Professor Abronsius: Yes there some other date fields as well. No, submit form via email. Simple!

In that case you need to check whether $_POST["DOB"] is in fact empty or not. If it's empty, don't pass it into the strtotime function, and don't use date. Those functions will always attempt to build a date from what you pass in. If you pass in something which isn't a parseable date value, then they just give you the default value (which, as you've discovered, and as is already documented (see here and here), is 01/01/1970). Demo: https://3v4l.org/UiRnn

$F_DOBNew = (!empty($_POST["DOB"]) ? date("d-m-Y", strtotime($_POST["DOB"])) : ""); ($F_DOB is completely redundant). Demo: https://3v4l.org/hUE9a

FYI - I just wanted to set the date format from YMD to DMY. What is the solution with few required and few unrequired fields - Form is submitting via email using PHP.
Kindly help!

I just wanted to set the date format from YMD to DMY...and you can still do that. But obviously that will only work if there's actually a date to convert in the first place! I believe my previous comment has already given you the solution. Have you tried it? Is there a problem?

The empty selection is not giving 01-01-1970. It is actually 0 but it is converted to the 01-01-1970 date as a result of being converted to Unix epoch time.
A possible fix is to check if the $F_DOB is empty or not, and add code handling it, for example skipping the conversion.
This is how to check it:
<?php
if(isset($_POST["BtnSubmit"])) {
    $F_DOB = $_POST["DOB"];
    if (!empty($F_DOB)) {
        // Date field is not empty, convert it to the desired format
        $F_DOBNew = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($F_DOB));
        echo $F_DOBNew;
    } else {
        // Date field is empty, handle accordingly (e.g., show a message)
        echo "Date of Birth not provided";
    }
}
?>


Great! This is working, do I need to do for every date field or there is any other way? Please assist.

I don't know how you have set up your project, but you can create an isValid function for example or a loop.
